# plt.gca().fill_between() does not work

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am confused about the use of matplotlib.

Here I have a dataframe df_10year and divide it into two smaller dataframes, one of maximum values of daily temperature for 10 years and the other of minimum values. Then I try to find the the min and max for each day by groupby and agg. I want to plot min and max values and color the region between these two lines.

```
df_10year_min = df_10year[df_10year['Element']=='TMIN']
df_10year_max = df_10year[df_10year['Element']=='TMAX']
tem_10year_min = df_10year_min.groupby('Month-Date').aggregate({'Data_Value':np.min})
tem_10year_max = df_10year_min.groupby('Month-Date').aggregate({'Data_Value':np.max})
```

The codes below works.

```
plt.plot(tem_10year_min.values, 'b')
plt.plot(tem_10year_max.values, 'r')
plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(tem_10year_min)), tem_10year_min['Data_Value'], tem_10year_max['Data_Value'], facecolor='yellow')
```

I just wonder difference between .values and [''], and the codes below don't work actually.

```
plt.plot(tem_10year_min['Data_Value'], 'b')
```

There is no picture showing up and it says: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12-31'. The dataframe looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aoMG.png).

```
plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(tem_10year_min)), tem_10year_min.values, tem_10year_max.values, facecolor='yellow')
```

And for this, no picture and it says Argument dimensions are incompatible.

Comment: `"the codes below don't work"`. In what way don't they work? Do you get an error message? Or does it plot something, but just not the right thing? Its best to put that information in your question so people can help you solve the problem.

Comment: @tom Thank you for your advice and I have added them.